# is it possible to open an external domain in a fancybox modal? cannot use iframe

Tags: jquery, fancybox

is it possible to open an external domain in a fancybox modal? cannot use iframe.
my problem is i have 2 domains pointing to the same directory:

http://www.elanartists.com/kitty_carmichael/

http://www.kittycarmichaelmusic.com

the "video" link points to the first domain

this works within it's own domain but returns the "The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later." error when attempted in the second domain.

thanks for any help!

Comment: You can't without setting CORS headers to pass same-origin security policy or using some other technique to save this restriction

Comment: thanks, claudio. would that be done by editing the .htaccess file? again, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi : you could actually, if there is not `X-Frame` restrictions

Comment: @user3194821 : your sites don't have any x-frame restrictions so you can open them in fancybox iframe if you need to http://jsfiddle.net/mro6cL8n/ ... you don't need any php code or CORS settings in your .htaccess.

Comment: Here you have an option to get cross domain content without using CORS https://github.com/jpillora/xdomain

Comment: @JFK: so far I understand from his question, he can't use iframes

Comment: @ClaudioRedi : as far as I understand the OP cannot use (inline) iframes, but opening the pages in a modal box. The method used the modal box is a different stuff. Anyways, suppose he applies CORS as you suggest: how would he open that page in fancybox after that?

Comment: @JFK: He wouldn't open the page but getting required content trough jquery `load`

Comment: @ClaudioRedi the question is not "can I get the content from a page?" but "can I open it in fancybox?"

Comment: @JFK: once you load content from a remote url and place it on your html becomes part of your page. You can do the same you would do with any other content, for instance, showing it inside fancy box. In any case without further feedback from user this discussion is a waste of time.

Comment: thanks very much for the responses. unfortunately, using fancybox.iframe presents the same problem. it screws up my responsive media queries within the modal. the php method allows the link to load properly in the modal, but the sub menu (within the modal page - other videos) runs into the same security problem. it seems as if setting the CORS headers to allow the first domain to be loaded might be the simplest solution. could you please provide an example of how to do this? thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because of a security issues.  An alternative solution is if you can use PHP to fetch the pages contents, then you can parse what you need etc, and display that in your site in a modal or however you wish.  **PHP CODE:**

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/';
    echo file_get_contents($url);
    //or place the contents into a variable to parse
    $contents = file_get_contents($url);
?>
```